# RecyclerView - Drag and Drop - move item over another item. (placeholder)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have an Adapter, Recyclerview and ItemTouchHelper.
I want to make placeholders on which, as a result of moving, it will be possible to place items.
Placeholders are now made as empty elements. But I don't know how I can put the element directly on this one.

[image]

My adapter:

```
public class DateTimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
    private List<MainItem> values;
    private RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
    private Activity context;
    private final OnStartDragListener mDragStartListener;
    private boolean initEmpty = false;

    public DateTimeAdapter(Activity context, List<MainItem> values, OnStartDragListener dragListener) {
        this.values = values;
        this.context = context;
        mDragStartListener = dragListener;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MainHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        switch (viewType){
            case (Constants.ITEM_HEADER_TEXT_VIEWTYPE):
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_group_item, parent, false);
                return new HeaderHolder(view);
            case (Constants.ITEM_EVENT_TEXT_VIEWTYPE):
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_wo_items, parent, false);
                return new ItemHolder(view);
            case (Constants.ITEM_PLACEHOLDER_VIEWTYPE):
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_placeholder, parent, false);
                return new PlaceHolder(view);
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MainHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(values.get(position));

        if (holder.getItemViewType() == Constants.ITEM_PLACEHOLDER_VIEWTYPE){

        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return values.get(position).getViewType();
    }

    protected LocalTime getStartTimebyHeader(int position){
        ListIterator<MainItem> listIterator = values.listIterator(position);
        while (listIterator.hasPrevious()){
            MainItem t = listIterator.previous();
            if (t.getHeaderItem() != null){
                DateTimeFormatter parse = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("HH:mm").toFormatter();
                LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(t.getHeaderItem().getHeaderText(), parse);
                return localTime;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    protected LocalTime getEndTimebyHeader(int position){
        ListIterator<MainItem> listIterator = values.listIterator(position);
        while (listIterator.hasNext()){
            MainItem t = listIterator.next();
            if (t.getHeaderItem() != null){
                DateTimeFormatter parse = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("HH:mm").toFormatter();
                LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(t.getHeaderItem().getHeaderText(), parse);
                return localTime;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                Collections.swap(values, i, i + 1);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                Collections.swap(values, i, i - 1);
            }
        }
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        values.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
```

My ItemTouchHelper

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, 0) {


            @Override
            public boolean canDropOver(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder current, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                if (target.getAdapterPosition() != 0 && target.getAdapterPosition() != dta.getItemCount()-1)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                Log.d("onMove", Integer.toString(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()) + " - " + Integer.toString(target.getAdapterPosition()));
                dta.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            }

            @Override
            public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                int dragFlags =  viewHolder.getItemViewType() == Constants.ITEM_EVENT_TEXT_VIEWTYPE ? ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN : 0;
                int swipeFlags =  viewHolder.getItemViewType() == Constants.ITEM_EVENT_TEXT_VIEWTYPE ? ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END : 0;
                return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
            }

            @Override
            public void clearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                showingDatas.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getEventItem().setTimeS(dta.getStartTimebyHeader(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                showingDatas.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getEventItem().setTimeE(dta.getEndTimebyHeader(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                dta.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
            }
        };

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvPlan);
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Resolved: Data class is used to distinguish between Normal View and Place Holder View. Using below list in adapter:

```
data class MyData(var type:Int, var name: String)
val list = mutableListOf(MyData(0,"PlaceHolder"),MyData(1,"Normal"),MyData(1,"Noraml"),MyData(0,"Place Holder"),MyData(1,"Normal"),MyData(1,"Normal"))
```

Custom Item Touch Listener class:

```
    ItemTouchHelper(object : RecyclerViewDragDetector() {
        override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {

            if (adapter.getItemViewType(viewHolder.adapterPosition) == 1){
                if (adapter.getItemViewType(target.adapterPosition)!= 1){

                    list[target.adapterPosition].type = 1
                    list[target.adapterPosition].name = "Normal"
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(target.adapterPosition)
                    list.removeAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
            return true
        }
        override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

Change Adapter as per your need. My sample adapter look like below:

```
    inner class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){
    private val viewTypeHeader = 0
    private val viewTypeNormal = 1
    inner class MyHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.normal_tv)
        fun bind(myData: MyData){
            textView.text = myData.name
        }
    }
    inner class MyHeaderHolder(view:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.header_tv)
        fun bind(myData: MyData){
            textView.text = myData.name
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == viewTypeHeader){
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false)
            MyHeaderHolder(view)
        }else {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
            MyHolder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
      if (getItemViewType(position) == viewTypeHeader){
            (holder as MyHeaderHolder).bind(list[position])
      }else{
          (holder as MyHolder).bind(list[position])
      }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (list[position].type == viewTypeHeader)
            return viewTypeHeader
        else
            viewTypeNormal

    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work. I want to place item with EVENT ViewType on item with PLACEHOLDER ViewType. How can I do it?

Comment: Okay, let me check and confirm you.

Comment: OK, I'm waiting

Comment: Issue has been solved. You can check my updated answer.

Comment: Just updated if else condition now. You can check it with just updated code.

Comment: Based on your code, the placeholder and the item are just changing types, right?
But I want to place an item ON a placeholder. That is, the placeholder should, as it were, disappear. And in its place to be an item.
That is, I drag and drop, point to the placeholder, release my finger, and an item appears in place of the placeholder. And the placeholder is removed.
As on an android screen with icons - when you hold down an icon, empty frames appear in places where you can move the icon.

Comment: Ohh, okay that's also possible . I will update you.

Comment: Okay, I hope for you

Comment: You can check it now. Everything works as per your expectation Bro.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229852/discussion-between-nrusingha-moharana-and--).